# Difference in writing a platform device driver for x86 and ARM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I previously worked on ARM Specific platform drivers, recently shifted to Intel Atom based. On ARM, it used to have `arch/arm/boot/dts/xx.dts` and `arch/arm/mach-xx/` for adding platform devices. I am not seeing these files or folders on x86. When I went into `arch/x86/...` there is no dts files or platform files.

How can i add my platform device information, if i want to add my platform device into Intel Atom platform? Where can i get the dts files specific to x86(assuming even though dts is not specific any architecture)?

Comment: There is a example, `arch/x86/platform/ce4100/falconfalls.dts`, kernel version is 3.18. May be it is a good start for you.

Comment: Thanks Chris, For your comment, this is the only place where i found. But there are many intel based boards. But what i found is they are using acpi info, similar to dts. But i am not sure how this acpi information is sent to linux. If i want to add any platform device. How can i add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two new features that allows you to have one driver for x86 and ARM worlds simultaneously. First is _DSD method in the ACPI which allows the vendor to supply any device properties they need to have the IP works properly. The second part is the unified device properties interface in the Linux kernel (look at *drivers/base/property.c*). Thus, if your device needs let's say `clock-frequency` property you just write in the driver something like this:

```
u32 clock_freq;
int err;

err = device_property_read_u32(…, &clock_freq);
if (err)
  dev_err(…, "A mandatory property not found!\n");
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, From where and how this ACPI infromation comes to Linux kernel

Comment: If it is a question the answer partially in the above text. `_DSD` method is specifically designed to supply key-value pairs of the device properties to the OS.

Comment: The _DSD (ACPI)info is sent from any boot code/ or it explicitly compiles with kernel. In ARM, generally we will generate dtb from dts and pass this to the kernel from uboot.

Comment: _DSD is a part of DSDT. Either you get it from firmware, or you supply an override with initrd. ARM64, btw, will use ACPI.